# Git in a local way

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I'm working with a messy client/boss and I need to set up a repository to be sure all my changes are staged and saved properly. My idea is to keep a directory called /c/repo/ where i'll have all the files I'm uploading to the different servers i'm going to work with, in that directory i'll have a directory for each project.
In the other hand, I'll have my working directories in /c/wamp/www/ so I can change and test my changes inmediately. When I've done with a task on a project, I'll just commit & push that project and then upload the directory of the project in /c/repo/

My filesystem will have this shape:

```
C
-Program Files
+Repo
--Project1
--Project2
--...
--ProjectX
+Wamp
-+Www
---Project1
---Project2
---...
---ProjectX
```

I've worked with git only with servers (github above all) but I don't know how to set up this environment properly in a local filesystem. Would you help me? I think it could be easy, but every link I open on a Google search I become more and more confused. Thank you everybody!!!!

Comment: The content of `C:/Repo` will be the same as the content of `C:/Wamp/Www`? If the content of `Www` is a git repo, i don't understand the need of having duplicate files. Your local repo is versioned, you'll keep the entire history of your modifications. You can have your local repo just by executing `git init` in the root folder of your repo, but it's not a very good idea...

Comment: When I start a task for project1, I'll go to my server and download the content via FTP into C:/Repo/Project1, then I'll clone it into C:/Wamp/www/Project1 and work with that. When I finish, after some commits, I'd push my changes to C:/Repo/Project1 and then upload whatever is in C:/Repo/Project to my server.

Comment: Why not having this process instead: Clone remote repo on your local machine, create a branch to make your modifications/commits, merge your branch with master and finally push everything on your remote server? That is exactly the same situation as you're looking for but instead of trying a complicate process you'll take full advantage of git!

Comment: I've worked like that so many times, and you're correct, that's the way to go, but I can't have a remote repo. My client/boss wants to edit anything anytime in the server :/

Comment: Have you the possibility to keep your remote repo and add a hook in order to clone it on another remote location that your boss will be able to modify at anytime? The problem is clearly in your boss process and it will be a better idea to fix this problem on the remote side, by doing so you're keeping a simple local structure

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your /c/repo is not a bare repository but something that can checkout from a repo.

You can try initialize a bare repository in /c/barerepo/, then clone it to /c/wamp/www/ and /c/repo. Then you work you way in /c/wamp/www. If you find it is in good shape, tag it. When you want to duplicate those files to other system you simply checkout that tag in /c/repo and copy to the remote servers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What is the point of initializing a bare repository and clone it into two other directories?

Comment: I am not very clear about what you want actually. I assume /c/wamp/www is a local testing version on this machine. The /c/repo is a tested version that to be distributed to many different machine. Both of them is a checked out version. Bare repo cannot be checkout. To store the "repository", meaning all versioned data, you may need any folder called /c/barerepo/. Am i understand your situation correctly?

Comment: /c/wamp/www is where my files will be meanwhile i'm working with them. /c/repo is where my tested files will be, ready to send via FTP to a web server (I'll do it by myself). I don't know why would I need a barerepo folder (I assume there's no code there, am I right?)

Comment: barerepo means it has all code, but it cannot checkout. That's mean if you navigate the folder of bare repo, it will not look like your project directory structure.

Comment: Sorry but I get your point less and less. If I have a folder with a different structure, why it's useful for me?